# Why would two tables with the same structure and data take up different amount of disk space?

Tags: sql-server

I was moving a table from a development to a production server and after moving the data I discovered that the two tables take up different amount of disk, space even though they are exactly the same.  I'm wondering what would cause this, and if there are any possible implications from this.

Here is a script that shows the structure of the two tables:

```sql
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BRIDGE_TABLE](
           [Column1_fk] [date] NOT NULL,
           [Column2_fk] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_BRIDGE_TABLE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
           [Column1_fk] ASC,
           [Column2_fk] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BRIDGE_TABLE]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BRIDGE_TABLE_1] FOREIGN KEY([Column1_fk]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PARENT_TABLE_1] ([KeyColumn])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BRIDGE_TABLE]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BRIDGE_TABLE_2] FOREIGN KEY([Column2_fk]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PARENT_TABLE_2] ([KeyColumn])
    GO
```

Here are the results from sp_spacedused displaying the difference in disk usage.

```
 Table Name          |rows       |reserved     |data       |index_size    |unused 
 --------------------|-----------|-------------|-----------|--------------|------ 
 Dev_Table           |98072577   |2502000 KB   |2491696 KB |9808 KB       |496 KB
 --------------------|-----------|-------------|-----------|--------------|------ 
 Production_Table    |98072577   |1560264 KB   |1550560 KB |7040 KB       |2664 KB
```

Edit: added results from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats query

```
tableName  |index_id |index_type_desc  |record_count |page_count |fragment_count |ghost_record_count |avg_record_size_in_bytes
-----------|---------|-----------------|-------------|-----------|---------------|-------------------|------------------------
Dev_Table  |     1   |CLUSTERED INDEX  |98072577     |311462     |292268         |0                  |14
-----------|---------|-----------------|-------------|-----------|---------------|-------------------|------------------------
Dev_Table  |     1   |CLUSTERED INDEX  |311462       |1206       |1206           |0                  |14
-----------|---------|-----------------|-------------|-----------|---------------|-------------------|------------------------
Dev_Table  |     1   |CLUSTERED INDEX  |1206         |5          |5              |0                  |14
-----------|---------|-----------------|-------------|-----------|---------------|-------------------|------------------------
Dev_Table  |     1   |CLUSTERED INDEX  |5            |1          |1              |0                  |14
```

```
tableName  |index_id |index_type_desc  |record_count |page_count |fragment_count |ghost_record_count |avg_record_size_in_bytes
-----------|---------|-----------------|-------------|-----------|---------------|-------------------|------------------------
Prod_Table |      1  |CLUSTERED INDEX  |98072577     |193820     |2686           |0                  |14
-----------|---------|-----------------|-------------|-----------|---------------|-------------------|------------------------
Prod_Table |      1  |CLUSTERED INDEX  |193820       |867        |867            |0                  |14
-----------|---------|-----------------|-------------|-----------|---------------|-------------------|------------------------
Prod_Table |      1  |CLUSTERED INDEX  |867          |3          |3              |0                  |14
-----------|---------|-----------------|-------------|-----------|---------------|-------------------|------------------------
Prod_Table |      1  |CLUSTERED INDEX  |3            |1          |1              |0                  |14
```

Comment: Add to your question the results of `select object_name(object_id) tableName, index_id, index_type_desc, record_count, page_count, 
       fragment_count, ghost_record_count, avg_record_size_in_bytes
from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(),object_id('BRIDGE_TABLE'),-1,0,'detailed')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the difference in size is due to fragmentation.

In the development environment, the fragmentation is high as is seen from the result of sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats query. This occurs when you have had deletes/updates of data over time leading to pages that are not completely filled (Assuming the fill factor on both development and production is the same).

When you moved your data from development to production, the fragmentation is quite low and that is why the space usage is low as well.

Try this to remove the fragmentation on your development server

```
ALTER INDEX PK_BRIDGE_TABLE ON [dbo].[BRIDGE_TABLE] REBUILD;
```

This should bring the fragmentation down and reduce space used on the table